# Python: get dictionary value from a dictionary within a tuple within a list and do something with it

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I've happened to get myself into a somewhat complex situation (for me at least).

I have a list, which contains a tuple, which contains multiple `combinations` from `itertools` of a dictionary and a value, presented below:

```
[({'a':'1,2,3','b':'2','c':'3'},0.25),({'a':'3,4,5','b':'4','c':'6'},0.50),({'a':'10,4,3','b':'6','c':'4'},0.25)
```

I need to get the values of only certain keys in order to do a calculation I want. Lets say I wanted to get the correlation of `'a'` for each dictionary with one other dictionary in the tuple:

```
for tuple in list:
    for dict in tuple:
        a = dict.get('a')
        for a_triplet in intertools.combinations(a, 2):
            np.correlate(a,b) for a,b in tuple
```

I know this code is probably egregious to many of you, but I am new to python (and coding in general) and don't know much about iterating through tuples and dictionaries.

## Update

Example of input:

```
[({'url': 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=QEC.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m&z=66&y=66', 'varreturns': '0.847771901', 'sdreturns': '0.920745296', 'name': 'Questerre Energy Corp (QEC.TO)', 'avgreturns': '1.292727273'}, 0.25), ({'url': 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=RBA.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m&z=66&y=66', 'varreturns': '16.6860534', 'sdreturns': '4.084856595', 'name': 'Ritchie Bros Auctioneers Inc (RBA.TO)', 'avgreturns': '20.71140496'}, 0.5), ({'url': 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=RDK.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m&z=66&y=66', 'varreturns': '0.038118899', 'sdreturns': '0.195240618', 'name': 'Redhawk Resources Inc (RDK.TO)', 'avgreturns': '0.400330579'}, 0.25)]
```

each tuple is a different stock that has been assigned a different weight through itertools

Given by code:

```
import itertools
import csv

names = []
stocks = []
with open('AbCtest.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    document = reader
    for row in reader:
        stock = row
        stocks.append(row)
        name = row['name']
        names.append(name)

weights_list = [(0.95, 0.025, 0.025),
               (0.90, 0.05, 0.05),
               (0.85, 0.075, 0.075),
               (0.80, 0.1, 0.1),
               (0.75, 0.125, 0.125),
               (0.70, 0.15, 0.15),
               (0.65, 0.175, 0.175),
               (0.60, 0.20, 0.20),
               (0.55, 0.225, 0.225),
               (0.50, 0.25, 0.25)]
def portfolios(document, weights_list):
    for stock_triplet in itertools.combinations(document, 3):
        for weights in weights_list:
            unique_weight_orders = set(itertools.permutations(weights))
            for weight_order in unique_weight_orders:
                yield zip(stock_triplet, weight_order)

for port in portfolios(stocks,weights_list):
    print port
```

Hopeful output example:

```
10.778966942999999
```

Given by:

```
('avgreturns' * weight) + ('avgreturns' * weight) + ('avgreturns' * weight)

#or, from taking the values given in "example of input"

(0.400330579*0.25)+(20.71140496*0.5)+(1.292727273*0.25)
```

**As for the correlation part:**

I understand this will be much harder, and will likely require use of `itertools` once again.

Let's say we name each tuple in the "example input": "a", "b", and "c". How would we find the correlation between "a" and "b", "b" and "c", and "a", and "c"?

for all possible combinations of 'avgreturns' in "example input":

```
corr_ab = numpy.correlate('avgreturns','avgreturns')
corr_ac = numpy.correlate('avgreturns','avgreturns')
corr_cb = numpy.correlate('avgreturns','avgreturns')
```

Thankful for any help recieved!

Cheers!

Comment: First lesson: Do not use `list`,`tuple` and `dict` as variables as they shadow the built-in functions

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: what is b supposed to be?

Comment: Please show us expected output for provided input data

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: I am aware that you would not use either of those in the code, just trying to explain my process

Comment: Your code still makes no sense.  The closest I can get is `([int(d.get("a", 1)) * b for d, b in l ])`

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: 'b' is the weight, or integer as the second element in the tuple. Such as 0.25 in the first one, 0.50 in the second one

Comment: @McLean25, a minimal example with the output you expect will help a lot.

Comment: also your real code copied and pasted(a minimal example) would be helpful ... I suspect you are trying to type it from memory

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: Added. Terribly sorry for the confusion, trying the best I can to explain. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Maybe using `.readline()`? Then storing each tuple into a different variable, and processing them from there?

Comment: @McLean25, where do `stocks,weights_list` come from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham weights_list added. I pull each stock from the document variable, which pulls the stocks I want from a CSV file that I had built previously with Scrapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(sum(float(d['avgreturns'])* b for d,b in l))
```

If you want a,b a,c  and b,c use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations
r = [float(d['avgreturns']) * b for d, b in l]
p = combinations(r,2) 
print(sum(r))
```

Comment: @McLean25, no worries, what do you want to pass to  `numpy.correlate`?

Comment: The dict key will be 'returns'. I deleted the key and values in order to reduce noise when I posted the question above as the value for 'returns' is a list of 121 int.

Comment: @McLean25, I presume correlate expects an iterable, do you want to pass a,b a,c and b,c to it?

Comment: the goal is to set the correlation for all combinations of the three stocks given in each loop. For example: `corr_stock1_2 = numpy.correlation(stock1['returns'],stock2['returns'])` and so on

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.

Comment: so `for a,b in p: print(numpy.correlate([a],[b]))`? Does it work for two single values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74290/discussion-between-mclean25-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0):

```
products = [int(my_dict.get('a',0))*b for my_dict,b in my_list]
```

might be what you are trying for ... ?

Comment: You would need `int(my_dict.get('a',0))`

Comment: Im not at all sure this is what he even wants(especially since all his values for a are lists of ints) ... but yeah